# How to disable the other field if the value is pre-selected (primeng multiselet)?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using multi-select from the primeng and set the selection Limit as 1. I am setting the value in onInit. What it is happening like, the value getting selected but not disabling for other values.

Following is the ts file

```
    export class AppComponent {

        cities1 = [
            {label:'New York', value:1},
            {label:'Rome', value:2},
            {label:'London', value:3},
            {label:'Istanbul', value:4},
            {label:'Paris', value:5}
        ];

        data = [];
        ngOnInit(){
            this.data = [4];
        }

    }
```

and the html file is

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]='data' 
      [selectionLimit]="1" ></p-multiSelect>
```

How to disable the other field if the value is pre-selected.?

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Update:** This issue is fixed in primeng version 8.0.2

This is an old [already reported issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7187) on which primeng
developers has not responded yet. I have created a [PR to fix this issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/7976),
until the PR is merged or the primeng team comes up with a fix, you can solve it
using a `ViewChild` fix.

**The `ViewChild` fix:**

primeng `MultiSelect` has a property named `maxSelectionLimitReached` which is set to
true when max limit is reached. You have to set it yourself in your `ngOnInit`. Follow
the comments as steps.

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';                    // import ViewChild
import { MultiSelect } from 'primeng/multiselect';                       // import MultiSelect


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('dataSelect', { static: true }) dataSelect: MultiSelect;    // declare ViewChild

  data = [];
  cities1 = [
    { label: 'New York', value: 1 },
    { label: 'Rome', value: 2 },
    { label: 'London', value: 3 },
    { label: 'Istanbul', value: 4 },
    { label: 'Paris', value: 5 }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [4];
    this.dataSelect.maxSelectionLimitReached = this.data.length >= 1;    // Set limit flag
  }
}
```

Add viewChild identifier to `<p-multiSelect>` element.

```html
<p-multiSelect #dataSelect [options]="cities1" ... ></p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: Many times I see myself doing hacks with ViewChild to change the default behavior of the component like above. I am feeling less bad now. :D

Answer (score 2):

Munim Munna answer is a pretty simpler than mine  but In our project we manage the selection Limit by set the disable to true for the options

```
 selectionLimit: number = 2;
 ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [4,5];
    this.updateOptionState(this.data)
  }

  updateOptionState(SelectedValue) {
    if (SelectedValue.length == this.selectionLimit) { // ⚡ check the limit 
      this.cities1
        .filter(item => SelectedValue.indexOf(item.value) === -1) // set other option 
        .forEach(i => {
          i.disabled = true
        })
    } else {
      this.cities1.forEach(item => item.disabled = false) //  reset
    }
  }
```

template

```
<p-multiSelect #dataSelect [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]='data' 
               (ngModelChange)="updateOptionState(data)"></p-multiSelect>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ls1xe1-gk2qvs)

Answer (score 0):

**PrimeNG multiselect** has a property **maxSelectionLimitReached** depends on **selectionLimit** and by default it is **false**. So, when you pass data through **ngOnInit** unfortunately it doesn't calculate it. You can do it easily by passing **true**

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.data = [4];
    this.dataSelect.maxSelectionLimitReached = true; // Just set true :)
}
```